# android imagespan not support auto next line

Tags: android, textview, auto, imagespan

android ImageSpan, in textview when last position show a big image is little，but my image is very big,I want to the ImageSpan auto
next line . I try overload size method and change size
equal textview width, but doesn't solve the problem

```
SpanabeleString contentSS=new SpanabeleString("hello word on the line [image]");
contentSS.setSpan(imageSpan,"[image]".start,"start".length,xxx);
//imageSpan not support auto new line;
```

I cannot change content,I hope use imagespan implement auto
next line function

Comment: textview setText spanableString with imagespan，but the image width is big, i hope imagespan support auto newline when setText set spanableString with imagespan

Answer (score 1):

An ImageSpan is an indirect subclass of [ReplacementSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ReplacementSpan). Flowing onto a new line is, evidently, something that `ReplacementSpan` (therefore an *ImageSpan*) cannot do. Here is a quote from an article [Drawing a rounded corner background on text](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/drawing-a-rounded-corner-background-on-text-5a610a95af5) by Florina Muntenescu who blogs about spans and the like. (Emphasis in the following quote is mine.)

> We need to draw a drawable together with the text. We can implement a custom ReplacementSpan to draw the background and the text ourselves. **However ReplacementSpans cannot flow into the next line**, therefore we will not be able to support a multi-line background. They would rather look like Chip, the Material Design component, where every element must fit on a single line.

I think that this is the flowing issue that you are having. As a work-around, you can insert the newline yourself when the condition occurs. There is no way that I know of to tell the *ImageSpan* to wrap.

Comment: @handler_mo I don't understand your comment.

Comment: my App is im app，when pc send Android ，i need textview setText with spanableString ，but show image with bug ，un support auto line in line last position

Comment: my SpanabeleString content have more diff  type span（list）. when insert the newline, all span position well change，I need change all span(list)  position .too much work to calculate all span position

Comment: ReplacementSpan  overload  draw ’\n‘ ？？